# Factor 1/2 in derivative of analytic complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Where does the factor of 1/2 come from in this derivative?

$$\frac{df}{dz}=\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} -i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)$$
where $f=f(z)$ is an analytic complex-valued function (Cauchy-Riemann conditions met) of the complex variable $z=x+iy$.

Comment: We get $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}$. If not, the right hand sides of these equations need to be divided by $2$. Wirtinger [chose to put define them this way](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/en/main/dms/img/?PPN=PPN235181684_0097&DMDID=dmdlog19). Well, and also for holomorphic $f$ we get $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ is $f'$. I guess this is a better reason.

Comment: As a very simple example of the second part of @plop's comment, what  do you expect $df/dz$ to be when $f$ is the identity function $z \mapsto z$?

Comment: @plop why is being holomorphic $f$ and $f'=df/dz$ is a better reason for the 1/2 factor?

Comment: @user135626 Well, because that way a symbol that looks exactly like Leibniz's $\frac{df}{dx}$ keeps having the same meaning as $f'$ in Lagrange's notation.

Comment: @plop I think basically, since $x=(z+\bar{z})/2$ and $y=-i(z-\bar{z})/2$, we have $\partial x/\partial z=1/2$ and $\partial y/\partial z=-i/2$, then the chain rule takes care of the rest by direct substitution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Many Coefficients Work

If $f$ is differentiable at $a$, and $z$ is shorthand for $x+iy$ with $x,y$ real-valued, then the Cauchy-Riemann equation(s) state that $\left.\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}f(z)\right|_{z=a}=-i\left.\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}f(z)\right|_{z=a}$. By taking the limit of the difference quotient along a horizontal line, we find that $f'(a)=\left.\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}f(z)\right|_{z=a}$. To simplify the notation, I'll just assume $f$ is differentiable in some open region and not bother with $a$.

By applying the above, we have $f'(z)=r\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+i(r-1)\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ for any complex number $r$, including special cases like:

- $r=1$ for $f'(z)=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$
- $r=\dfrac12$ for $\boxed{f'(z)=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} -i \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)}$
- $r=2$ for $f'(z)=2\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} +i \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$
- $r=1-i$ for $f'(z)=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}-i\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$

## Why 1/2?

But there is a reason why we write $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} -i \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$ in particular, as opposed to picking other coefficients that yield $f'(z)$.

Suppose that $f$ is *not* necessarily complex differentiable, but the partials $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ exist (and are continuous, say) on an open region. Then we could reasonably write $\mathrm df=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\mathrm dx+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\mathrm dy$.

If $z=x+iy$ and $\overline{z}=x-iy$, then applying $\mathrm d$ to both sides of those equations, we can reasonably write $\mathrm dz=\mathrm dx+i\mathrm dy$ and $\mathrm d\overline z=\mathrm dx-i\mathrm dy$. Solving, we get $\mathrm dx=(\mathrm dz+\mathrm d\overline z)/2$ and $\mathrm dy=-i(\mathrm dz-\mathrm d\overline z)/2$. This means that $\mathrm df=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm dz+\mathrm d\overline z}{2}-i\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm dz-\mathrm d\overline z}{2}$ and so $\mathrm df=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}-i\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\mathrm dz+\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+i\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\mathrm d\overline z$.

This suggests defining the "Wirtinger derivatives" $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}-i\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \overline z}=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+i\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$ so that we can write the tidy $\mathrm df=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}\mathrm dz+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \overline z}\mathrm d\overline z$.

In the special case where $f$ is differentiable at a relevant point, $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \overline z}=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+i\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)=0$ by Cauchy-Riemann, so that $\mathrm df=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}\mathrm dz+0\mathrm d\overline z=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}\mathrm dz$, so that we could divide by $\mathrm dz$ to consistently write $\dfrac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dz}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}-i\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$.